# drawLine doesn't draw line over BufferedImage

Tags: java, swing, bufferedimage, graphics2d

I've got a following problem. I want to draw lines over BufferedImage, but they don't show up. If i don't load the image, they will show. What is the problem? Here is my code:

```
@Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        prepareImage();
        g.drawImage(buffer, 0, 0, null);
        g.dispose();
    }
    private void prepareImage() {
        Graphics g = buffer.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(mapImage, 0, 0, null);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        for (Line line : lines)
            g.drawLine(line.x1, line.y1, line.x2, line.y2);
        lines.clear();
        g.dispose();
    }
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  For an SSCCE that uses images, either hot-link to them or generate them in code.

Comment: Also, it looks like when you draw the "buffer" image over top of the "lines image".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see two issues in your code:

1. You shouldn't be calling g.dispose() in paintComponent
2. Since you clear the lines collection, the next time paintComponent is called (and you have no control on that), no line will be drawn.

Comment: The g.dispose() should be used. It is disposing the Graphics object returned from the createGraphics() method. It is not disposing the Grpahics object passed to the paintComponent() method.

Comment: You are talking about the one in the prepareImage whereas I was talking about the one in paintComponent

Comment: Sorry, you where perfectly clear about that, Not sure what I was thinking.